# Не могу загрузить видео с ютуба вк и локал

Tags: php, angularjs, yii2

My yii action

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Video();

        $uploaded = false;

        switch (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            case "youtube":
                $model->name = Yii::$app->request->post('name');
                $model->url = str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", Yii::$app->request->post('youtube'));
                break;
            case "vimeo":
                $model->name = Yii::$app->request->post('name');
                $model->url = Yii::$app->request->post('vimeo');
                break;
            case 'vk':
                $model->name = Yii::$app->request->post('name');
                $model->url = Yii::$app->request->post('vk');
                break;
            default :
                new InvalidParamException('Not valid data', 400);
        }
        if ($model->load($_POST)) {

            $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

            if ($model->validate()) {
                $uploaded = $file->saveAs(Video::UPLOAD_DIR);

            }
        }


        if ($uploaded) {
            return $this->redirect('index');
        }else{
            return new ServerErrorHttpException('we cannot uplkoad your video ',500);
        }
    }
```

My angular controller 'use strict';

```
main.controller('VideosController', function ($scope, $routeParams, appService)
{
    var video; 
    $scope.save = function () {
        if ($scope.video) {
            appService.postData('index.php/site/create', $scope.video).then(function (data)
            {
                    $scope.alert = { showAlert:true, msg: angular.fromJson(data).mesg, alertClass: 'success' };
                },
                function (error) {
                    alert("Can't download this video");
                });
        } 
    };
});
```

Comment: for English question we have `stackoverflow.com`, I can translate your post?

Comment: you get any error? какя ошибка?

Comment: просто  не записывает в базу данных.редиректит на index.php и все